# Calculate average VBA from dynamic table

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I ve a table on Excel with the week number and the weight (in Kg.)

Somebody can insert his weight every day during a week or just once or not at all. I can't manage that.
Then my table can literally change. from zero to 7 even more lines a week (like the yellow side of the image).

What I wanna do is to calculate the weight average per week. and then I will have one line for each week, when i got at least one weight (sometimes I won't have any line). We can have week without any weight so then I don't want this line at all. We can also easily have a weight for the week 2 but between the weeks 5 and 6 in the yellow table. That would happen if someone insert his weight after others.

How can I say this two weeks are similar, so we calculate the average for this two weight ?

[image]

I hope it's enough clear with this picture

Comment: Create a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) with Weeks on the left and Avg of Weight in the data area?

Comment: The worksheet function `AverageIf()` seems like it might solve the problem even without VBA. Your description of what you want to do is too vague to say for sure, but perhaps you could start by reading the help page for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula below in Column C to calculate average(assume Week in column A and Weight in column B)

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B)
```

Average Column Copy->PasteSpecial value only,
then Remove Duplicates base on Week and the new Average Column